# How to reduce lines with list comprehensions in Python?

Tags: python, list

I have some syntax :

```
l_one = [ x for x in someList ] # list with duplicates
l = []
l_two = [ l.append( y ) for y in l_one if y not in l ] # duplicates removed
```

Both l and l_two are the same lists without duplicates. Is there way to reduce lines and maybe have oneliner?

EDIT :
Correction - l_two are the "Noned" list.

Comment: Please check [How do you remove duplicates from a list](http://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, they aren't the same. `.append()` returns `None` because it modifies the list in place, so `l_two` is a list with a bunch of `None`s. However, `l` will be the list with no dupes.

If you want to remove duplicates from a list, you can make it into a set:

```
l_two = list(set(l_one))
```

Note that this will remove order.

---

Try using a for-loop instead of a list comprehension if you want to use unhashable types:

```
l_one = [x for x in someList]
l_two = []
for i in l_one:
    if i not in l_two:
        l_two.append(i)
```

Or:

```
from itertools import groupby
l_two = [key for key, value in groupby(l_one)]
```

Comment: Now it wouldn't work, because "someList" members are also lists. So, you know, "unhashable" err.

Comment: Thanks, +1 at comments, but it would not be reduction.

Comment: @Alex Ah, you are correct. Is it necessary for a one liner? Sparse *is* better than dense...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33759/discussion-between-alex-and-haidro)

Comment: Your `groupby` approach won't remove noncontiguous duplicates.  You'd have to sort first.

Comment: @DSM Alex and I talked in chat, and it seemed to help him

Comment: @Haidro: ? I don't follow.  You can try it yourself, say with `l_one = [1,2,1,2]`.  If you know all the duplicates are contiguous, it'll work, but without that knowledge it doesn't do the same thing as your other two.

Comment: @DSM Ah, I see now. Maybe OP already has this? I'm not sure what he has, but, and I quote, "Wow! I works. Edit your answer to vote you."

Answer (score 1):

IF I'm understanding correctly, you're starting with a list called `someList` which may have duplicates, and you want to end up with the same list but with duplicates removed?

You could start by removing your first line of code, which just duplicates someList into a new (but identical) list called l_one:

```
>>> someList = [ 3,1,4,1,5,9,2,7 ]
>>> l = []
>>> [ l.append(y) for y in someList if y not in l]
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None]
>>> print l
[3, 1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 7]
>>>
```

This works even if the elements of someList are themselves lists:

```
>>> l = []
>>> someList = [[1,2],[2,1],[1,2],[3,4]]
>>> l = []
>>> [ l.append(y) for y in someList if y not in l]
[None, None, None]
>>> print l
[[1, 2], [2, 1], [3, 4]]
>>>
```

Comment: Well, someList contains other lists which are collected in. But I can't be so broad in explaining. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Not sure what difference that makes - works fine even if the element of someList are lists.

Comment: l_one = [ x.attributeList for x in very_large_attributeList_container ], so it has to be l_one. Excuse me if I was not clear at first. Thanks for your time.